# push after rebaseing, how to?

Tags: git, rebase

i want to push the code to origin server after rebasing op applied.
conflict is reported every time.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the GitFaq, see http://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_won.27t_.22git_push.22_work_after_I_rebased_a_branch.3F